# How to make images appears 2 in a row when device is medium and 1 on small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 6 images, i want to make them responsive when resizing screen.
On medium devices, 2 images must be shown in a row, on small devices 1 image, as well i cannot figure out how to make Heading text responsive too, when resizing it should get smaller, i used max-with for the .overlay-header

Here is my code:

**UPDATED:**

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kani339/yz5rdts0/7/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <div class="image-container">

            <div class="image-portfolio col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="img-block">
                            <img src="http://listtoday.org/wallpaper/2015/12/latest-computer-technology-6-widescreen-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-header">
                        <h1>Heading</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="text-overlay">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, minus aliquid. Atque accusamus, minima recusandae unde, velit ea laborum accusantium aut amet consequatur. Quaerat, libero, omnis eos maiores nulla nam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="image-portfolio col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="img-block">
                            <img src="http://listtoday.org/wallpaper/2015/12/latest-computer-technology-6-widescreen-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-header">
                        <h1>Heading</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="text-overlay">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, minus aliquid. Atque accusamus, minima recusandae unde, velit ea laborum accusantium aut amet consequatur. Quaerat, libero, omnis eos maiores nulla nam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="image-portfolio col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="img-block">
                            <img src="http://listtoday.org/wallpaper/2015/12/latest-computer-technology-6-widescreen-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-header">
                        <h1>Heading</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="text-overlay">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, minus aliquid. Atque accusamus, minima recusandae unde, velit ea laborum accusantium aut amet consequatur. Quaerat, libero, omnis eos maiores nulla nam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="image-portfolio  col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="img-block">
                            <img src="http://listtoday.org/wallpaper/2015/12/latest-computer-technology-6-widescreen-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-header">
                        <h1>Heading</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="text-overlay">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, minus aliquid. Atque accusamus, minima recusandae unde, velit ea laborum accusantium aut amet consequatur. Quaerat, libero, omnis eos maiores nulla nam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="image-portfolio  col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="img-block">
                            <img src="http://listtoday.org/wallpaper/2015/12/latest-computer-technology-6-widescreen-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-header">
                        <h1>Heading</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="text-overlay">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, minus aliquid. Atque accusamus, minima recusandae unde, velit ea laborum accusantium aut amet consequatur. Quaerat, libero, omnis eos maiores nulla nam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="image-portfolio  col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="img-block">
                            <img src="http://listtoday.org/wallpaper/2015/12/latest-computer-technology-6-widescreen-wallpaper.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-header">
                        <h1>Heading</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="text-overlay">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate, minus aliquid. Atque accusamus, minima recusandae unde, velit ea laborum accusantium aut amet consequatur. Quaerat, libero, omnis eos maiores nulla nam!</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}


.image-portfolio {
    margin:2px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-block img {
  height: 250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.5s;

}

.overlay-header {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 225px;
    height: 55px;
    background: rgba(202,205,206,.7);
    margin-top: 50px;

}

.overlay-header h1 {
    line-height: 20px;

}

.text-overlay {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  bottom: 120px;
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.image-portfolio:hover .img-block img {
    cursor:pointer;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}

.image-portfolio:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.image-portfolio:hover .text-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}

.image-portfolio:hover .img-block img {
  filter: brightness(40%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to show only 2 images in a row on medium devices, you should use col-md-6 class this means out of 12 columns on the medium device, your one image will take 6 columns.

And then you want only 1 image in a row on small devices, you should use col-sm-12 class this means out of 12 columns on the small device, your one image will take all 12 columns.

col-lg-3 means on a larger device, 4 images will show up in a row.

```
<div class="image-portfolio col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
```

**For reference**

```
.col-xs = *Extra small devices (ie Phones) (<768px)

.col-sm = Small devices (ie Tablets) (≥768px)

.col-md = Medium devices (ie laptops, or small desktops) (≥992px)

.col-lg = Large devices (ie Desktops) (≥1200px)*
```

> Image Responsive

For making image responsive simply add img-responsive class

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="link/to/your/image">
```

For header you have to write css at different widths

```
@media(max-width:768px){
      h1{
          font-size:20px;
      }
}
```

something like above

Comment: this seems not helped, i updated link. I have a problem in css which i cannot figure out

Comment: @Andrew first clear your custom stylesheet and then try